# add timestamp at end of url with .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

i have a wordpress site and want to add a timestamp in url like this:

date,hour,minutes at end of my url (?201503291854) example:

```
example.com/pagename?201503291854 

example.com/page/2/?201503291854
```

but if user visit the url
with 1854 at end and if time now is 19:00
link will be

```
example.com/pagename?201503291900
```

Comment: What is your purpose for wanting to do this?

Comment: It does if you're trying to do something that shouldn't be done using htaccess

Comment: So you want htaccess to redirect a request to always include the latest timestamp? This is what will happen, 1: request is for `/pagename`, 2: htaccess redirects browser to `/pagename?201503301900`,3: browser requests `/pagename?201503301900`, 4: htaccess redirects browser to `/pagename?201503301905`, 5: browser requests `/pagename?201503301905`, htaccess redirects browser to `/pagename?201503301911`... etc, e.g. infinite redirect loop, since the timestamp is always changing and after each request the htaccess will simply redirect the browser again

Comment: i have some code and it works with example.com/pagename?201503291854 

but with example.com/page/2/?201503291854   i get redirect loop /
if u can help me i can pay  u    contact me in  arlind@ live .com.ar

Answer (score 2):

I had to find a way to do that in order to avoid the caching system of Facebook and Twitter (for their og:tags), while reaching a dynamically generate picture (so their cache system didn't trigger the change).

Here is how I done that.

You will, of course, need Apache mod_rewrite.

Here is what I put in my .htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://stuff.com/profile.php?customURL=$1&ts=%{TIME_YEAR}%{TIME_MON}%{TIME_DAY}_%{TIME_HOUR} [NC,L]
```

And here is what you can insert :

Year:

> %{TIME_YEAR}

Month :

> %{TIME_MON}

Day :

> %{TIME_DAY}

Hour :

> %{TIME_HOUR}

Min :

> %{TIME_MIN}

Sec :

> %{TIME_SEC}

When tested on the twitter validator, I then successfully got :

> profile.php?customURL=testing&ts=20160913_16

or (with min and sec)

> profile.php?customURL=testing&ts=20160913_164108

Here you can find good cheatsheet for modrewrite :
http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html

In case the above link goes down, here it's on webarchive (at today date) :
http://web.archive.org/web/20160821181903/http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/mod_rewrite-variables-cheatsheet.html